# Python driver for film scanner reflecta rps?

Tags: python, usb, driver, scanning

anyone experience with custom drivers for reflecta film scanners? I want a very basic python script to directly control a Reflecta RPS 10m film scanner via USB. I just need to start a scan with a certain dpi and the output stream.
Any starting points or hints?

I found the SANE project, but I'm not experienced enough to draw out the information how to control a scanner via the usb interface directly by python.

Comment: You might specify your OS.

Comment: I could basically live with every OS. Which one would be the most easy one? Preferred would be macOS, then Windows, then Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I got 2 different scanners working under **macOS**. It was maybe 2 years ago, and I don't have access to a scanner similar to yours...

So, as Apple doesn't see fit to provide a software package manager, I needed to install [homebrew](https://brew.sh) first. Then install the SANE stuff:

```
brew install libusb
brew install sane-backends
```

Then find the scanner:

```
sane-find-scanner
found USB scanner (vendor=0x04b8 [EPSON], product=0x012a [EPSON Scanner]) at libusb:253:005
```

You want the last word on the above line, I used this to find an EPSON scanner:

```
device=$(sane-find-scanner | awk '/EPSON/{print $NF}')
echo $device
libusb:253:005
```

Now you can scan full-page, high-resolution, in colour with:

```
scanimage --device epson:$device --mode color --resolution 300 --format=tiff > scan.tif
```

Then I modify the image with **ImageMagick** because I am faster with that than working out the correct scanner commands! So, if I wanted a lower-resolution, greyscale version of the scanned TIFF file from above, I might use:

```
brew install imagemagick

magick scan.tif -colorspace gray -resize 50% SmallGrey.jpg
```

---

If you get stuck with the commands, I found a good way to debug is with:

```
SANE_DEBUG_SNAPSCAN=128 scanimage -L
```

---

I have found a £30 Raspberry Pi to be even better at recognising scanners so I often use one of them too. The procedure is pretty similar.

Comment: Thanks for the clear instructions. I tried but didn't find my scanner. Also looked deeper into the documentation of SANE: The reflecta scanner is not supported (yet). Besides that I would like a more pythonic solution with packages from conda or pip.